# Why the origin of this complex is moving away from the origin (0,0)?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, complex-geometry

Why does the origin of the complex line z is moving *away* from the origin?

$$Let\;z=x+i\cdot y \\\;z-1\;=\;\;(x-1)+i\cdot y\;$$

Following that I would say that the coordinates of the origin of z are (x-1, 0) but the book draws the origin of the line at (x+1, 0)

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: What do you means by" coordinates of the origin of z " ?

Comment: Sorry if unclear, I mean the intersection of the complex line x with the x-axis (it's a semi-line, starting from a point (x, 0) and ending at (k, y)